# Rails habtm joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have this relationship between **categories, products & brands**:

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  belongs_to :brand
end
```

How can I select all categories by specified brand with this relations?
I try this but get an error

```
b = Brand.find(1)
Category.joins(:products).where(:products => b.products)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did the right thing with the join, just add a more complex where definition:

```
Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:brand_id => 1})
```

Answer (score 4):

Controversially HABTM's are rarely, if ever, a good design and IMO just about the only thing Rails got wrong.

Introduce an xref table to join products and categories and use has_many :through on both sides of the relationship so you end up with

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :categories, :through => :products # This is now allowed in Rails 3.x and above
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_category
  has_many :products, :through => :product_category 
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :product_category
  has_many :categories, :through => :product_category
end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :categories
end
```

This gives you the best flexibility with the least amount of code re-factoring for you plus a much more intuitive path to get whatever data you need on either side of the relationship and will enable you to achieve the following

```
b = Brand.find(1)
b.categories.all
```

**Update**
The above is totally untested code and I have just corrected a glaringly stupid mistake I made. If you have any issues implementing this then come back

Comment: Purely my opinion, but I don't agree that HABTM is poor design.  It is a great, foundational start to a lookup table.  If your schema doesn't dictate a complex relationship, then KISS.  It is easy enough to promote a HABTM association to standalone model when/if the need arises.