# Trying to access attribute in join table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Ok I think I have two problems which need to be fixed**

I've got the following tables:
`Student`, `Register` and a join table which displays the records that 1 register has many students in it, called 'Registers_Students' which looks like this: [image].

I had to create the `Register_Students` table via `rails g migration CreateStudentRegister`, which looked like this:

```
class CreateStudentRegister < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :registers_students, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer  :register_id
    t.integer :student_id
    t.boolean :present
    t.time :time_of_arrival
  end
 end
end
```

Now, I want every register to have a number of students, and for every student, I want them to have a `present` status of true/false, and every student should also have a `time_of_arrival` time. 
However, I have no way of accessing the `time_of_arrival` or `present` attributes, as I want to set them.

The way I want to change these attributes for every student, is in the `register/show.html.erb` using the following code:

```
<% @register.students.each do |student| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= Register.find(@register).present %></td>         #Doesn't work
      <td><%= student.university_id%></td>
      <td><%= student.first_name.titlecase%></td>
      <td><%= student.last_name.titlecase%></td>
      <td><%= Register.find(@register).time_of_arrival %></td> #This doesn't work
      <td><%= student.time_of_arrival%></td>                   #Nor does this

  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The reason I want it to be displayed in the `show` page, is so that the register can be edited with marking the student as either being present or absent, and also mark their time of arrival using a checkbox (That part hasn't been implemented yet, but if any of you guys know how to implement it, I'd love to hear about it).

Thanks guys for any answers in advance

EDIT: Added models

Model for `Students`:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :registers
  validates :university_id, :length => { :minimum => 10}, #Checks that the University ID is 10 characters long
            :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}, #Checks that the University ID is unique, regardless of case-sensitivity
        :format => { :with => /[wW]\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d/, #University ID needs to be in the right format via regex
                     :message => "Needs to be in the right format i.e. w123456789"}

  default_scope :order => 'LOWER(last_name)' #Orders the students via last name
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :university_id

  def name
    first_name.titlecase + " " + last_name.titlecase
  end
end
```

And this is the other model for the `Register`

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
  belongs_to :event
  attr_accessible :date, :student_ids, :module_class_id, :event_id
end
```

Comment: What's not working? If the graphic you entered is up-to-date, then `present` and `time_of_arrival` return `nil`, and `<%= nil %>` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Yes I understand that,but there's no way for me to manually update `present` or `time_of_arrival` attribute. Even through SQLite it won't let me update it

Comment: habtm is rarely if ever a good idea - See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243566/rails-habtm-joins/14244978#14244978

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
You need to set up a model to access the registers_students table

That table name doesn't follow rails conventions or normal symantics so can I suggest you

1) roll back your db by 1 migration (assuming that the creation of this table was the last migration) using

`rake db:rollback`

2) delete the migration from the db/migrations folder

3) use the built in rails model generator

```
rails g model student_register register_id:integer student_id:integer #etc
```

Now migrate your database Then set up your has_many and belongs_to relationships so you can use them in your view.

You will now have for each student a student_registers array you can loop through and access the present field on
**End update**

1)

```
  <td><%= Register.find(@register).present %></td>         #Doesn't work
```

You have an instance of @register already so there is no need to go abnd read the database again to find the same one. Just use the attribute you want directly on the @register object

```
<td><%= @register.present %></td>
```

you original code although it is bad design should have worked

If that doesn't work then you have a more fundamental problem that is not possible to guess at with the little information you have provided so come back and edit your question and leave a comment if this is the case.

2)

the same goes for

```
  <td><%= Register.find(@register).time_of_arrival %></td> #This doesn't work
```

3)

And because you say this doesn't work

```
  <td><%= student.time_of_arrival%></td>                   #Nor does this
```

I start to suspect your statements of not working and suggest that it is working perfectly
Perhaps you have no data in those fields to display. So enter some data and all will be good.

4) There are 3 main ways to edit multiple records on a screen using rails helpers.
I suggest you read up on fields_for

As a starting point http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Also check out this http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually
Ryan Bates has done other railscasts on this subject so have a trawl through that website.

Comment: Hey @jamesw, 1) doesn't work, I just played around with the code to clarify that these commands don't work, as I'm getting this error message: `undefined method 'present' for #<Register:0x007fe8da3c12c8>
`. 
2 and 3) Give me this erros: `undefined method 'time_of_arrival' for #<Student:0x007fe8dd57e220>`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is access these attributes, through console or web, doesn't matter, as long as I can access them

Comment: @teenOmar OK, you need to post up the contyroller actions AND all the models involved in this process. I'm pretty sure I know what is happening (You probably haven't set up a model to deal with the registers_student table). I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's probably it, I haven't got a model to access it I think. Which controller actions do you need? They are just the template actions, haven't made any changed to any of them (Both `Register` and `Student`). For the models I will edit my question and include it as well

Comment: When you say, `set up your has_many and belongs_to relationships so you can use them in your view`, how exactly should i set them up (considering you stated that using HABTM is a bad idea. Sorry to bother, but could you just let me know how the associations should be in the `Student`, `Register` and `Student_Register` model? Thanks so much by the way ;)

Comment: @teenOmar In your case I would suggest that you take the "if it works don't fix it" approach regarding your existing relations, just bear in mind that it might not give you the flexibility you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25898/discussion-between-jamesw-and-teenomar)

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `has_many :through` association.

See rails guide for this, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html