# Accessing distant models using has many through and separate join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

How do I access universe from actor (and vice versa)?

I have three models
`universe`
`character`
`actor`

Universes and characters are associated via a separate join table using has_many through.
Characters and actors are associated via a separate join table using has_many through.

(Note: the reason why i decided against `has_and_belongs_to_many` and instead chose `has_many through` is because of reasons outlined in the accepted answer [Rails habtm joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243566/rails-habtm-joins) )

I do not wish to store foreign keys in any of the three primary tables.

```
universe
    \
     \
     universe_character_tie
     /
    /
character
    \
     \
     character_actor_tie
     /
    /
actor
```

---

I want to somehow associate universes and actors... through characters.
Two approaches come to mind:

1)
If I do a `has_many through` `characters` type of association, that will

1. bypass the other two `has_many through` join tables; and
2. require foreign keys in `characters, right?

2) 
Don't do anything. calling `actor.character.universe` will already work... (is this true)?

I am not sure whether my haunches are correct, and I am somewhat stuck in coding it.
Can someone shed light, please?

Comment: `actor.character.universe` won't work because rails won't know which character you want or which universe

Comment: you're right. I am being way too loose with my wording. assuming that i specify which actor and which universe, what would the call code look like in the current setup of two has_many through relationships (if it's even possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Universe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :universe_character_ties
  has_many :characters, through: :universe_character_ties

  has_many :actors, through: :characters
end

class UniverseCharacterTie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :universe
  belongs_to :character
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :universe_character_ties
  has_many :universes, through: :universe_character_ties

  has_many :character_actor_ties
  has_many :actors, through: :character_actor_ties
end

class CharacterActorTie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :actor
  belongs_to :character
end

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :character_actor_ties
  has_many :characters, through: :character_actor_ties

  has_many :universes, through: :characters
end
```

Then you can call `actor.universes` or `universe.actors` ...

Hope this helps

Comment: change `throught` to `through` :)

Comment: Oups you're right. And sorry @jvnill I didn't see your answer before I posted mine...

Comment: awesome, so from what I already have, i only need to add `has_many :actors, through: :characters` to Universe, and `has_many :universes, through: :characters` to Actor. =D

Comment: How does rails make `through: :characters` work, even if characters doesn't contain any foreign keys? does using `through` only apply for helper methods? Does it know to access the other two join tables?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if this is written as an answer as I have not tested the following.  I believe you can nest the associations as long as you declare them like

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :character_actor_ties
  has_many :characters, through: :character_actor_ties
  has_many :universe_character_ties, through: :characters
  has_many :universes, through: :universe_character_ties
end
```

Then just call `actor.universes` to get all universes that are associated to an actor's characters.

EDIT (explanation)

The code above relies heavily on rails' naming convention.  From the rails api, the `through` option

> Specifies an association through which to perform the query. This can
>   be any other type of association, including other :through
>   associations. Options for :class_name, :primary_key and :foreign_key
>   are ignored, as the association uses the source reflection.

That means that calling `actor.characters` will go through `character_actor_ties` and look for an association named `character` and will use the rules declared on that association to build the sql query associating an `actor` and `character`.

Just follow this pattern until you get to a model that is associated directly to `universes` and that is `universe_character_ties`.

Comment: I did wonder if this would work as I have a similar setup on one of my projects but only with one has_many through.  Would be awesome if it works

Comment: Can you explain a bit of what goes on in the background of 
   `has_many :universe_character_ties, through: :characters`

   `has_many :universes, through: :universe_character_ties`

Comment: do the last two lines (before `end`) necessitate additional foreign keys anywhere?

Comment: nope, they don't need additional foreign keys anywhere.